# What does SDelete do after it reached 100%?

Tags: sdelete

About 2 hours ago, [SDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) (`sdelete -z`) reached 100% - at least that's what it says:

[image: SDelete at 100%]

But since then, the disk is >90% busy and the average response time is very high. Write speed is at ~ 7 MB/s. I believe it was at 27 MB/s when SDelete started.

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 1):

It is flushing the cache - either its own one or the one of the operating system.

The figure "100%" probably appears when all write commands have been successfully issued.
Especially when the application is about secure deleting, the 100% should appear after total completion.

Comment: 15+ GB of cache? As you can see in the Process Monitor log, the writes are non-cache.

Comment: Also in [this description on how SDelete works](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/41c0515b-9971-48d3-a4c5-70ae0e48bbf3/sysinternals-sdelete-wipe-free-space?forum=miscutils) it says that SDelete uses non-cached file IO.

Comment: According to your source, SDelete does not only process the clusters that contain data. It has to process every free MFT entry. The percentage counter is probably only referring to the deletion of the content of free clusters.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why it is so slow is because you're using the old version 2.0 of SDelete. Version 2.04 is much faster.

For version 2.0: using [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), you can see that it's still writing.

[image: Screenshot of Process Monitor]

The file size that Process Monitor reports corresponds to the used disk space (if the disk was empty).

[image: Screenshot of drive properties]

The drop in throughput is explained by the constant rotation speed of the disk. The disk is written from the outside (where you have a long circumference) to the inside (where you have a short circumference).

So, just wait until the program exits and don't look at the percentages it reports.